# How does ContourDetect work for arrays?

Tags: plotting, list-manipulation

By the Wolfram Documentation, ContourDetect gives a binary sparse array in which 1 corresponds to zeros and zero crossings in an array. However, in the example:

```
In[7]:= ContourDetect[{4, 0, 1, -2, 1, -2, -3, -1, 3}] // Normal
Out[7]= {0, 1, 1, 0, 1, 0, 0, 0, 1}
```

Why -2 at position 4 and 6 corresponds to 0s? Didn't we cross zero by going from 1 to -2? What makes a number in an array a zero crossing?

Comment: `ListPlot[{#, ContourDetect[#] // Normal}, Joined -> True] &@{4, 0, 1, -2, 1, -2, -3, -1, 3}` as well as with other lists suggests, that `0` is always replaced with `1`. Apart from that, any pair of adjacent numbers `{..., a, b, ...}`, where `a b` is strictly negative, is subject to a replacement where the negative number becomes a zero, and the positive - a one.

Comment: What about ContourDetect[{4, 0, 1, -2, 1, -2, -3, -1, 3}, 2] for example? Does it find the places where the the array of points cross 2?

Comment: No, what led you to think that way? That's equivalent to `ContourDetect[Chop[N@list, 2]]`